# GreasePencil: Can I pick a vertex color from a reference image in the viewport?

Tags: grease-pencil

A Grease Pencil question: Is there a way to pick a color (in Vertex color draw mode) from a reference image thats placed in the 3d viewport?

In Photoshop that would be clicking on a spot while holding down Alt. When I use the Eyedropper tool it either gives me a swatch or a material, neither of which I want. I want to pick and draw strokes without having to switch to anything else. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

While drawing in vertex paint mode, click on the color swatch next to the vertex paint button at the top of the window. This will open up the color options. Click on the left side of the color swatch below the RGB picker area as if you were going to manually choose a color. This will open up another color picker which has an eyedropper on it. Select that eye dropper and sample the color from your image. This will set the current vertex color swatch to the color you sample.

[image]